# google drive file link automatically change format in spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am implementing some download and upload file functionality in google drive through google app-script storing the drive link in google sheet. upload works fine but after some time the link is turn into some kind of hyperlink as like below

[image]

so that's why I am no longer able to get the link simply writting .getDisplayValue()
`const ss = SpreadSheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet() let url = ss.getRange().getDisplayValue()`

Any Suggestion ...?

I tried Adding .getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl() But It also does not worked as It is not a HyperLink

Comment: From your showing image, I think that the bottom link is the smart chip. About `but after some time the link is turn into some kind of hyperlink as like below`, in your situation, for example, the URL of `https://drive.google.com/file/d/###/view?usp=share_link` is automatically changed to the smart chip, although you are not doing anything. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes. And then I am no longer able to get the link address from appscript

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your sample image and your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue and workaround:

From your sample image, in your situation, the link of the file is changed to the smart chip. In the current stage, unfortunately, there are no methods for managing the smart chips on a Spreadsheet. So, in this case, it is required to use a workaround. The workaround is as follows.

1. Convert Google Spreadsheet to XLSX data.

   - By this, the file links of the smart chip are converted to simple strings and hyperlinks.
2. Convert XLSX data to Google Spreadsheet.
3. Retrieve the hyperlinks from the cells.

This method is from [How to get in Apps Script the value of a dropdown in a Google Doc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72914087) and https://tanaikech.github.io/2022/10/27/retrieving-values-of-calendar-events-of-smart-chips-on-google-document-using-google-apps-script/ .

When this flow is reflected in a sample script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and set `range` that you want to retrieve the hyperlinks as A1Notation. In this sample, Drive API is used. So, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  const range = "Sheet1!A1:A10"; // Please set the range you want to retrieve the hyperlinks.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?exportFormat=xlsx&id=" + ss.getId();
  const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob();
  const tempId = Drive.Files.insert({ mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, title: "temp" }, blob).id;
  const tempFile = DriveApp.getFileById(tempId);
  const tempSS = SpreadsheetApp.open(tempFile);
  const res = tempSS.getRange(range).getRichTextValues().map((r, i) => r.map((c, j) => ({ value: c.getText(), url: c.getLinkUrl() || "", range: { row: i + 1, column: j + 1 } })));
  tempFile.setTrashed(true);
  console.log(res);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

```json
[
  [{"value":"sample value","url":"https://drive.google.com/file/d/###/view?usp=share_link","range":{"row":1,"column":1}}],
  ,
  ,
  ,
]
```

#### Note:

- As another approach, in your showing sample image, if you want to convert the file links of the smart chip to the normal value with the hyperlink, how about the following sample script? In this sample, `range` is overwritten by the normal values with the hyperlinks obtained by converting from XLSX data.

  ```js
  function myFunction2() {
    const range = "Sheet1!A1:A10"; // Please set the range you want to retrieve the hyperlinks.

    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?exportFormat=xlsx&id=" + ss.getId();
    const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getBlob();
    const tempId = Drive.Files.insert({ mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, title: "temp" }, blob).id;
    const tempFile = DriveApp.getFileById(tempId);
    const tempSS = SpreadsheetApp.open(tempFile);
    const r = tempSS.getRange(range);
    const tempSheet = r.getSheet().copyTo(ss);
    tempSheet.getRange(r.getA1Notation()).copyTo(ss.getRange(range));
    ss.deleteSheet(tempSheet);
    tempFile.setTrashed(true);
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [Retrieving Values of Calendar Events of Smart Chips on Google Document using Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://tanaikech.github.io/2022/10/27/retrieving-values-of-calendar-events-of-smart-chips-on-google-document-using-google-apps-script/)
- Related thread

  - [How to get in Apps Script the value of a dropdown in a Google Doc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72914087)