# AppScript not reading dropdown in Google Docs Table

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google app script that (is supposed to) scan all the documents in a google drive folder and pull the contents of a table in each document into a combined spreadsheet table.  My script does the basics of this but it skips cells with drop downs.  Is it possible to modify the script so that it captures the dropdown selection? See below for links to example.

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13FRm2SDduplegE58NnD0AjDwwXQ1TZ7vEOcTC8M58ao/edit?usp=sharing) with script and combined table. [Folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KW8OPJr9D9qkJI2C5Zea5WbX6iPAwYOz) it scans with example documents.

```
function combineTablesFromDocuments() {
  var folderId = "1KW8OPJr9D9qkJI2C5Zea5WbX6iPAwYOz"; // Folder ID containing the documents
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Name of the combined sheet

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
  var combinedData = [];

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var document = DocumentApp.openById(file.getId());
    var tables = document.getBody().getTables();
    var fileName = file.getName(); // Get the file name

    for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
      var table = tables[i];
      var tableData = tableTo2DArray(table, fileName); // Pass the file name to the tableTo2DArray function
      combinedData = combinedData.concat(tableData);
    }

    document.saveAndClose();
  }

  combinedData = combinedData.filter(row => row.length === 4 && row.some(cell => cell !== '')); // Exclude rows that don't have exactly four columns or contain only empty cells

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var combinedSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  if (!combinedSheet) {
    combinedSheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(sheetName);
  } else {
    combinedSheet.clear();
  }

  var headerRow = ["File Name", "Date", "Type", "Note"]; // Add "File Name" to the header row
  combinedData.unshift(headerRow); // Add the header row to the beginning of the combinedData array

  var range = combinedSheet.getRange(1, 1, combinedData.length, 4); // Adjust the range to include the additional column
  range.setValues(combinedData);
}

function tableTo2DArray(table, fileName) { // Pass the file name to the function
  var tableData = [];

  for (var i = 1; i < table.getNumRows(); i++) { // Start from index 1 to exclude header row
    var rowData = [fileName]; // Add the file name as the first column of each row
    var row = table.getRow(i);
    var isEmptyRow = true;

    for (var j = 0; j < table.getRow(i).getNumCells(); j++) {
      var cell = row.getCell(j);
      var cellText = cell.getText();
      rowData.push(cellText);

      if (cellText !== '') {
        isEmptyRow = false;
      }
    }

    if (!isEmptyRow) {
      tableData.push(rowData);
    }
  }

  return tableData;
}
```

Comment: if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76508393/17926478) answer actually worked for you (at least for your initial concern), don't forget to either upvote or mark it as 'best answer'. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran some tests, by adding just the dropdown list to a Google Docs (outside a table), and retrieving the information on the dropdown list. Even the `getText()` return blank, is not showing up in elements either, and all the other methods I use I get the same result. I was not able to find a method specifically for retrieving information in a dropdown list, either. After some search, I found that this is a feature request inside the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/264568839) of Google.

I found a workaround too, which is to convert the Google Doc to DOCX, I found some options to convert the file to HTML and user the [XmlService.parse()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service#parse(String)) to get the data. You can see some examples in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72914087/how-to-get-in-apps-script-the-value-of-a-dropdown-in-a-google-doc).

**Update:**

First, you will need to add the [Google Drive Advance](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) services:

[image: Drive services]

After that, you need to add explicit scopes to the Apps Script, you do this by enabling the “appsscript.json” manifest file from the `Project settings`.

[image: “appsscript.json” manifest]

Return to the editor, select the manifest, and add the scopes manually:

[image]

```
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
  ]
```

Lastly, paste the following code with the new modifications:

```
function combineTablesFromDocuments() {
  // Folder ID containing the documents
  var folderId = "1KW8OPJr9D9qkJI2C5Zea5WbX6iPAwYOz";
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Name of the combined sheet

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
  var combinedData = [];

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();

    // Add a new variable called id. 
    //This one will get the ID of the file which needs to be converted
    let id = file.getId()
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?exportFormat=docx&id="
      + id;

    // creates the Oauth token for the URL fetch
    var param = {
      method: "get",
      headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
    };

    //converts the file to a bloc

    let blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, param).getBlob();

    // returns the blob to a temp Google Doc

    let tempFileId = Drive.Files
      .insert({ title: "temp", mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS }, blob,).id;

    // I replace the file.getId() with the temp file ID

    var document = DocumentApp.openById(tempFileId);

    var tables = document.getBody().getTables();
    var fileName = file.getName(); // Get the file name

    for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
      var table = tables[i];
      // Pass the file name to the tableTo2DArray function
      var tableData = tableTo2DArray(table, fileName);
      combinedData = combinedData.concat(tableData);
    }

    document.saveAndClose();

    //deletes the temp file
    Drive.Files.remove(tempFileId)

  }
  // Exclude rows that don't have exactly four columns 
  //or contain only empty cells
  combinedData = combinedData.filter(row => row.length === 4 && row.some(cell => cell !== '')); 

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var combinedSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  if (!combinedSheet) {
    combinedSheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(sheetName);
  } else {
    combinedSheet.clear();
  }
  // Add "File Name" to the header row
  var headerRow = ["File Name", "Date", "Type", "Note"]; 
  // Add the header row to the beginning of the combinedData array
  combinedData.unshift(headerRow); 

  // Adjust the range to include the additional column
  var range = combinedSheet.getRange(1, 1, combinedData.length, 4); 
  range.setValues(combinedData);
}

function tableTo2DArray(table, fileName) { 
  // Pass the file name to the function
  var tableData = [];

  // Start from index 1 to exclude header row
  for (var i = 1; i < table.getNumRows(); i++) { 
    
    // Add the file name as the first column of each row
    var rowData = [fileName]; 
    var row = table.getRow(i);
    var isEmptyRow = true;

    for (var j = 0; j < table.getRow(i).getNumCells(); j++) {
      var cell = row.getCell(j);
      var cellText = cell.getText();
      rowData.push(cellText);

      if (cellText !== '') {
        isEmptyRow = false;
      }
    }

    if (!isEmptyRow) {
      tableData.push(rowData);
    }
  }

  return tableData;
}
```

And the result is:

[image: result]